# How to detect the right font to use depending on the langage

Tags: python, unicode, localization, fonts

For a program of mine I have a database full of street name (using GIS stuff) in unicode. The user selects any part of the world he wants to see (using openstreetmap, google maps or whatever) and my program displays every streets selected using a nice font to show their names. As you may know not every font can display non latin characters... and it gives me headaches. I wonder how to tell my program "if this word is written in chinese, then use a chinese font".

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I want to use non-standard fonts. Arial, Courier and some other can display non-latin words, but I want to use other fonts (I have a specific font for chinese, another one for japanese, another one for arabic...). I just have to know what font to chose depending of the word I want to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need information about the language of the text.
And when you decide what fonts you want, you do a mapping from language to font.

If you try to do it automatically, it does not work. The fonts for Japanese, Chinese Traditional, and Chinese Simplified look differently even for the same character. They might be inteligible, but a native would be able to tell (ok, complain) that the font is wrong.

Plus, if you do anything algorithmically, there is no way to consider the estethic part (for instance the fact that you don't like Arial :-)

Comment: Arial is not so bad... :) Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use utf-8 text and a font that has glyphs for every possible character defined, like Arial/Verdana in Windows. That bypasses the entire detection problem. One font will handle everything.

Comment: Thanks for this fast answer... I forgot to mention that I want to display non-standard font. My work is kind of "artistic" and I want to use specific-beautiful fonts. Let me edit my post.

Comment: What? Arial isn't beautiful? Please wait there and some MS goons will be over to correct your viewpoint shortly, using spare MS Bob CDs.

Comment: Ho! no, no... it's me, I have bad tastes. After considering your comment, it seems obvious that Arial is enough for any typographic project. I will immediately rewrite my program to display only Arial. Thank you so much (and thanks to the MS guy who has created this so beautiful font). :D

Comment: Ugly font or not, the answer is incorrect :-) Not only that there is no font that can handle everything, but it can't be. Several reasons: Chinese Simplified, Chinese Traditional, and Japanese share code points, but the look should be slightly different. Some of the most visible differences include the positioning of the punctuation characters (see for instance this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_unification#Examples_of_language_dependent_characters)

Comment: Second reason: Unicode allocates more than 100K code points, while some of the tables in OpenType are limited to 64K. And in fact you need more than 100K glyphs, because you have language-specific glyphs for the same code point, you have ligatures, etc. So you can't represent all the Unicode ranges unless the OpenType specs changes. and operating systems/text engines change to support the new spec, and you get a font designed to follow the new spec.